# How to install module of python in VS code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

Please share process how to install external modules

i cann't access modules
[ss of my vs code screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7buZ.png)

Comment: I guess you're on PowerShell. Just type the command `python` to go into the Python CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to manually install packages/modules like pandas you should first install a package manager like [PIP](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_download/), or [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution) if you have not done so already.

Once you install follow instructions of either to setup the package manager.

Using PIP you should be entering the following command once installed correctly:

```
$ pip install package_name
$ pip3 install package_name
```

If you are using Anaconda, Miniconda, or any other package manager follow the instructions [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html)

**NOTE: Before asking a question, check if there are any similar questions that have already been answered**